# Seat Tube Size?

Tags: seattube

I was just wondering if there was anyone on here who knows or could help me figure out my seat tube size. My bike is a 2008 Kona Stinky Deluxe. I don't have any calipers for checking either, and I've already checked online, with no luck.

Comment: According to http://downloads.konaworld.com/docs/2008_tech_info.pdf - 30mmx350mm

Comment: @mattnz can you convert to an answer?

Comment: As a rule, the seatpost will have its diameter marked on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this technical doc](https://downloads.konaworld.com/docs/2008_tech_info.pdf#page=13), page 13 - 30mmx350mm

> **Stinky Deluxe**
> Stem 10 deg. 50mm all sizes
> Seatpost 30.0 x 350mm

Looks like Kona used 30.0 and 27.2 in those days, if its not 30.0mm it will almost certainly be 27.2, you can measure accurately enough with a ruler to tell between those two.

30mm is not a common seat post size except for Kona. There is a reasonable amount of discussion on dropper posts for Kona's that have 30mm seat posts,  the usual advice is run the very common 27.2 and shim it.